# Partir una cadena de valores separados por coma en PHP, para realizar un bucle e insertar en la base de datos conforme a esos valores

Tags: php, sql, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$rut_medico = $_GET["rut_medico"];
$fecha_inico = $_GET["fecha_inico"];
$dias = $_GET["dias"];

$sql_conexion = new sql_functions();
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_anulamedico values(SC_ANULAMEDICO.nextval, $rut_medico, TO_DATE('$fecha_inico','YYYY-mm-dd') || ' 00:00:00', TO_DATE('$fecha_inico','YYYY-mm-dd') + INTERVAL '$dias' DAY - INTERVAL '1' DAY || '23:59:59', NULL,NULL, NULL)";

$result = $sql_conexion->updateQuery($sql, null, true);
```

Este es el formulario HTML:

```
<p>Ingrese el rut del médico (sin puntos ni dígito verificador, ej: 26.315.162-5 = 26315162)</p>
<p>Si es más de un rut sepárelos por comas</p>
<input class="FormManual" name="rut_medico" id="rut_medico" type="text" value="" placeholder = "Rut" required><br>
<p>Ingrese la fecha de inicio y el número de días que durará la sanción.</p>
<input class="FormManual" name="fecha_inico" id="fecha_inico" type="date"  maxlength="10" value="" placeholder = "Fecha de inicio" required><br>
<input class="FormManual" name="dias" id="dias" type="number"  maxlength="10" value="" placeholder = "Días de sansión" required><br>
```

No se como ejecutar el insert varias veces en caso de que el usuario inserte mas de un "rut_medico". El input seria por ejemplo así "123456, 17482, 18876".
Estoy pensando como hacer un bucle para que se ejecute el insert uno por uno con cada uno de esos datos. La bd es oracle.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que explotar el valor de rut_medico, partiéndolo por las comas. Y luego hacer el loop sobre el resultado. Esto te servirá tanto si sólo ponen un rut_medico, como varios (separados por coma).

```
$rut_medicos = explode(',', $_GET["rut_medico"]);
$fecha_inico = $_GET["fecha_inico"];
$dias = $_GET["dias"];

$sql_conexion = new sql_functions();

foreach ($rut_medicos as $rut_medico) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_anulamedico values(SC_ANULAMEDICO.nextval, " . (int)$rut_medico . ", TO_DATE('$fecha_inico','YYYY-mm-dd') || ' 00:00:00', TO_DATE('$fecha_inico','YYYY-mm-dd') + INTERVAL '$dias' DAY - INTERVAL '1' DAY || '23:59:59', NULL,NULL, NULL)";

    $result = $sql_conexion->updateQuery($sql, null, true);
}
```

Nota: He casteado a (int) el valor de $rut_medico para evitar problemas en la instrucción SQL. Esto además hace que dé igual si hay espacios junto a las comas.